# How to stop Waze from playing sound alerts in Android, quickfix

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth, alerts, waze

If you have bluetooth on and set it to alerts only you still get blasted by tons of terrible notifications in Waze like Animals on Shoulder, Vehicle Stopped on Shoulder, and the super loud recalculating route sound.

Answer (score 1):

This is the quickfix. Hopefully Waze doesn't not find out a way to kill my new found bliss of not having vehicle stopped on shoulder and recalculating alerts blasting over my Bluetooth, but here it goes.

The quick fix is to copy 0 length files over the problem child .tts and .mp3 files as root. It looks like waze recently moved their app files to /data/data/com.waze/waze which is why changing things in /sdcard/waze did nothing.

So for the English Jane voice I opened the tts.db file with a SQL editor and found the filenames for all these terrible alerts. I then create zero length .tts files for all these and copy into `/sdcard/waze/` for safe keeping and then periodically overwrite the files in the Jane folder as root but you may only have to do it once.

```
cp -f /sdcard/waze/*.tts   /data/data/com.waze/waze/tts/database/Jane/
```

- 1435594475-5862.tts
- 1457677779-906910-3.tts
- 1457677779-914343-5.tts
- 1457677779-914372-7.tts
- 1457677779-999286-14.tts
- 1457677782-172010-43.tts
- 1457677783-73520-54.tts
- 1457677783-73539-55.tts
- 1457677783-960407-66.tts
- 1457677784-50223-68.tts
- 1466453351-190271-3.tts
- 1466453351-191171-5.tts
- 1466453351-191184-7.tts
- 1466453351-191900-8.tts
- 1466453351-192754-14.tts
- 1466453358-437709-68.tts
- 1466453358-437795-70.tts

Create zero length files into /sdcard/waze/sound and copy to eng and heb folders as root

```
cp -f /sdcard/waze/sound/*.*   /data/data/com.waze/waze/sound/eng/

cp -f /sdcard/waze/sound/*.*   /data/data/com.waze/waze/sound/heb/
```

- alert_1.mp3
- bonus.mp3
- click.mp3
- ft.mp3
- m.mp3
- message_ticker.mp3
- ping.mp3
- ping2.mp3
- pop_up.mp3
- reminder.mp3
- TickerPoints.mp3 <---- I think this is really the recalculating sound
- tip.mp3
- ToggleProvider.mp3

And voila, Waze doesn't suck any more with it connected to Bluetooth, at least in Los Angeles.

Enjoy the free air again people that hated this problem as much as I did.